# How to customize the \label{}

Tags: equations, numbering, ntheorem

I would like to change the presentation of the command `\label{}`. More precisely for the theorems of `ntheorem`.

In fact I created a theorem called "assumption", and I would like to refer an assumption with a letter instead of a number.

So I have into my preamble

```
\newtheorem*{hyp}{Assumption}}
```

I declare into my article

```
\begin{hyp}[\ref{H}]\label{H}
\end{hyp}
```

When I refer to `H`, `(1)` is printed, but my aim is to get `(H)` with a dynamic link. I know the command `\tag{}` in the environment `\begin{equation}` but that's all.

I propose this minimal example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,backref=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}

{\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem*{hyp}{Assumption}}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}[\ref{sheme}]\label{sheme}
Bla bla
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}[H]
Bla bla
\end{hyp}

\begin{equation} 1=1, \tag{\textbf{H}$_{Mon}$} \label{mono} \end{equation}
Reference to mono: (\ref{mono}), with an hyperlink
\end{document}
```

It is possible to change a label in an `equation` environment. How can I do somewhere else?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Please provide a minimal example document that othes can copy and test without having to add anything. This makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: As far as I know `\newtheorem*` does not use a counter at all. So what should `\label` do then?

Comment: You've not loaded `hyperref` at all. Just saying `\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}` is not enough.

Comment: I rectified ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Saying `\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}` isn't enough here. The `hyperref` package must be loaded too!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

{\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem*{hyp}{Assumption}}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}[\ref{sheme}]\label{sheme}
Bla bla
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}[H]
Bla bla
\end{hyp}


\begin{equation} 1=1, \tag{\textbf{H}$_{Mon}$} \label{mono} \end{equation}
Reference to mono: (\ref{mono}), with an hyperlink

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created the following environment

```
\newenvironment{assumption}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{#1}),leftmargin=60pt] 
\item\label{#1}}
{\end{enumerate}}
```

and get what I want.

Comment: I see -- where's the hyper link in this? ;-) And it's only a fragment of solution